# Getting infinite loop when outputting the reversed linked list

Tags: go, linked-list

I'm learning Go and have written the following code to reverse a linked list. However, the code doesn't work as expected.

Here's a Node structure along with the function for printing and reversing the list.

```
type Node struct {
    number   int
    previous *Node
    next     *Node
}

func PrintList(node *Node) {
    for n := node; n != nil; n = n.next {
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
}

func ReverseList(node *Node) {
    var nextNodeRef *Node

    for n := node; n != nil; n = n.previous {
        if n.next == nil {
            n.next = n.previous
            n.previous = nil

            *node = *n

            break
        } else {
            nextNodeRef = n.next

            n.next = n.previous
            n.previous = nextNodeRef

            if n.next == nil {
                node = n
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that when I reverse the list and call `PrintList` I get a seemingly infinite output of all the elements of the list except for the last one (which used to be the first element)

Here's my `main` function:

```
func main() {
    myList := Node{1, nil, nil}
    myListAddress := &myList

    AddNumber(2, myListAddress)
    AddNumber(3, myListAddress)

    fmt.Println("My list:")
    PrintList(myListAddress)

    ReverseList(myListAddress)
    fmt.Println("My list reversed:")
    // here I always get list elements that contain 3, 2, 3, 2...
    PrintList(myListAddress)
}
```

And here's the `AddNumber` function that I use:

```
func AddNumber(number int, node *Node) *Node {
    if node == nil {
        log.Fatal("No Node provided")
    }

    var newNode Node

    for n := node; n != nil; n = n.next {
        if n.next == nil {
            newNode = Node{number, n, nil}
            n.next = &newNode

            break
        }
    }

    return &newNode
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*node = *n
```

This line does not do what you think it does. You probably hoped it'd change that outer `*Node` to point to the new head (old tail), yes? Well no, it simply replaces the node at that location. Which explains why the former first value is missing.

So before this last step you have something like this

```
nil <- 3 <=> 2 <=> 1 -> nil
       ↑           ↑
       n           node, myListAddress
```

Then you replace `node` with value of `n` (which is `nil <- 3 -> 2`). This makes the structure look like this:

```
      prev
 ┌────────────────┐
 │                │ node, myListAddress    
 ˅                │╱
nil <- 3 <=> 2 -> 3 ──┐
             ^        │next
             └────────┘
```

By the way, this list is so small that this diagram may be misleading. Here's how it looks with more elements:

```
      prev
 ┌────────────────────────────┐
 │                            │ node, myListAddress    
 ˅                            │╱
nil <- 5 <=> 4 <=> 3 <=> 2 -> 5 ──┐
             ^                    │next
             └────────────────────┘
```

You can either use a `**Node` there. Or simply return the new head from the function:

```
func ReverseList(node *Node) *Node {

    for n := node; n != nil; n = n.previous {
        if n.next == nil {
            n.next = n.previous
            n.previous = nil

            return n
        } else {
            n.next, n.previous = n.previous, n.next
        }
    }

    return node
}
```

Then

```
myListAddress = ReverseList(myListAddress)
```

Comment: I spent _waaaay_ much more time on these arrows than I should have :/